# How are user specific Sieve files created?

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot, sieve

My Dovecot's protocol_lda is as follows:

```
protocol lda {
    log_path = /var/log/mail/dovecot-deliver.log
    auth_socket_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
    postmaster_address = malmeida@itclinical.com
    mail_plugins = sieve
    mail_plugin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lda
    global_script_path = /etc/sieve/globalsieverc
    sieve_before = /etc/sieve/sieve_before
    sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve
```

}

I touched the `/home/someuser/.dovecot.sieve` to create the file, created the directory `~/sieve`, and created `/home/someuser/someuser.sieve` with the contents:

```
require ["fileinto"];

if address :domain :is "From" "gmail.com" {
  fileinto "XXX";
  stop;
}
```

However, mail comming from a gmail account is being filed in INBOX instead of XXX.

**EDIT:**
In a nutshell, the use case I am interested is:

*As an admin of a postfix configuration with one Mailbox per linux system user*

*I want one sieve rules file per user (in their home directory) in addition to the default global rules*

*So that each user's rules are separated (easier to read) and each use can configure his own rules*

**Edit 2018-08-29:**
It ended up working by having:

- a symlink ~/.dovecot.sieve pointing to /home/malmeida/sieve/name.sieve
- The script in ~/sieve/name.sieve
- Note that if the script has a different name, dovecot will log (e.g. if file is called active_sieve) " Warning: sieve: file storage: Active Sieve script symlink /home/user/.dovecot.sieve is broken: Invalid scriptname (points to /home/user/sieve/active_sieve)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sieve has a concept of active sieve script. The `.dovecot.sieve` is not a directory, but should be symbolic link to the active sieve script.

In other words:

- ~/sieve may contain several scripts
- ~/.dovecot.sieve should be a symlink to one of these scripts

With this setup, dovecot will be able to use the per-user configuration based on the files within each user's home directory.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Just for clarification before accepting this answer - does that mean that the sieve directory may only include one file, and that .dovecot.sieve should symlink to that file?

Comment: Also, for clarification - is the interpretation correct that the "sieve =" directory with a "~/" notation  is used to access per-email-user directives, based on what each user has on his ~/ directory?

Comment: You can have more than one file, but only one can be active at a time, which the symlink points to. doveadm sieve can be used to manipulate these with recent enough dovecot. At least 2.2.0 or later.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I updated my answer and will accept this one!

Comment: Should these symliks be created manually per each user? Probably Roundcube can make a job for that?

Comment: Managesieve protocol can be used to activate these and roundcube has sieve plugin, so that should be enough.